Formula not working when parsing set a dynamic range in Google spreadsheet formula ARRAYFORMULA
I am using ARRAYFORMULA in Google spreadsheet by parsing a dynamic range to it. However, it seems having conflict with the formula, which the return is not as expected.
Table



Column P
Expected Result




A
001


A
002


B
001


A
003



=arrayformula(TEXT(countifs('RAW'!$P$2:P2,'KAON RAW'!P2:P),"000"))

The reason I parse "'RAW'!$P$2:P2" is because to restrict the range up until the current row. This will keep the last row always the biggest number of the repeated value. The Column P will add records sometimes.
However, this dynamic range seems having conflict with ARRAYFORMULA.
Can someone helps? Or any alternative because the file is not always opening or active.
The above script generate this unexpected result

Use map() with countif(), like this:
=map(P2:P5, lambda(cell, 
  text(countif(P2:cell, cell), "000") 
))

To handle all rows down to the bottom, and show blanks on rows where there is no data, add if():
=map(P2:P, lambda(cell, 
  if(len(cell), 
    text(countif(P2:cell, cell), "000"), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
))

See map() and countif().

It works fine at my end. Thank you.

Try arrayformula in this way-
=ArrayFormula(IF(P2:P="",,COUNTIFS(P2:P,P2:P,ROW(P2:P),"<="&ROW(P2:P))))

Another easier way to use MAP() function. Try-
=MAP(P2:P5,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(P2:INDEX(P:P,ROW(x)),x)))


